# Generate Detatched PGP/Signature File

Tags: gnupg, pgp, signature

I am creating a few metalinks for an installer similar to wubi. It requires me to create a MD5SUMS-metalink file which I have done but the program will not continue because it requires a `MD5SUMS-metalink.gpg` file.

I am not sure how to generate this and it needs to be something along the lines of

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.11 (GNU/Linux)

iEYEABECAAYFAlNRiYIACgkQRhgUM/u3VFGPaACcC1l9IwsQdOzI7kJbgQTm1jEw
RloAnRwAtqUAlc+p5/EKpyIsA6JL4GDi
=IMv7
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

which is what the official Ubuntu one contains.

How can I generate this detached signature in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A detached GPG signature can be created like so:

```
gpg -ab -o SignedFile.gpg FileToSign
```

Options used are:

- `-a` to create ASCII output instead of binary
- `-b` to create a detached signature,
- and `-o` to specify the output file.

Comment: FYI: The -s (--sign) option is redundant when the -b (--detach-sign) option is being used.